# c++ error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals on calling inside of static function

Tags: c++

i have a problem with calling a template function inside of a static method.
here my codes:
baseEvent.h

```
#ifndef BASE_EVENT_H
#define BASE_EVENT_H

#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

class baseEvent
{
public:
    template<typename Sender,typename EventArgs>
    using pureEvent = std::function<void(Sender, EventArgs)>;
    template<typename pureEvent>
    using eventMap = std::unordered_map<int, pureEvent>;

    template<typename Sender, typename EventArgs>
    struct Event
    {
        int AddEvent(pureEvent<Sender, EventArgs>);
        void RemoveEvent(int);
        void LaunchEvents(Sender, EventArgs);
    private:
        eventMap<pureEvent<Sender,EventArgs>> Events;
    };
};

#endif
```

and baseEvent.cpp

```
    #include "baseEvent.h"




template <typename Sender, typename EventArgs>
int baseEvent::Event<Sender, EventArgs>::AddEvent(pureEvent<Sender, EventArgs> pure_event)
{
    auto uniqeID = 0;
    if (Events.rbegin() != Events.rend())
        uniqeID = Events.rbegin()->first + 1;
    Events.insert(std::make_pair(uniqeID, pure_event));
    return uniqeID;
}

template <typename Sender, typename EventArgs>
void baseEvent::Event<Sender, EventArgs>::RemoveEvent(int uniqeID)
{
    auto it = Events.find(uniqeID);
    if (it != Events.end())
        Events.erase(it);
}

template <typename Sender, typename EventArgs>
void baseEvent::Event<Sender, EventArgs>::LaunchEvents(Sender sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Events.empty())return;
    for (auto& singleEvent : Events)
    {
        singleEvent(sender, e);
    }
}
```

anotherClass.h

```
    #include "baseEvent.h"
class anotherClass
{
public:
    typedef baseEvent::pureEvent<nullptr_t, int> ballEvent;

    static void Update();

    static int AddOnChangeOwnerEvent(ballEvent);
    static void RemoveOnChangeOwnerEvent(int);
    static void LaunchOnChangeOwnerEvents(int);
private:
    static baseEvent::Event<nullptr_t, int> OnChangeOwnerEvents;
};
```

anotherClass.cpp

```
#include "anotherClass.h"

baseEvent::Event< nullptr_t, int> ball::OnChangeOwnerEvents;

void ball::Update()
{
    LaunchOnChangeOwnerEvents(0);
    //.
    //.
    //.
}

inline int anotherClass::AddOnChangeOwnerEvent(ballEvent ball_event)
{
    return OnChangeOwnerEvents.AddEvent(ball_event);
}

inline void anotherClass::RemoveOnChangeOwnerEvent(int uniqeID)
{
    return OnChangeOwnerEvents.RemoveEvent(uniqeID);
}

inline void anotherClass::LaunchOnChangeOwnerEvents(int event_args)
{
    return OnChangeOwnerEvents.LaunchEvents(nullptr, event_args);
}
```

it gives me this error :

> Error 2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void
>   __thiscall baseEvent::Event::LaunchEvents(std::nullptr_t,int)"
>   (?LaunchEvents@?$Event@$$TH@baseEvent@@QAEX$$TH@Z) referenced in
>   function "public: static void __cdecl
>   anotherClass::LaunchOnChangeOwnerEvents(int)"
>   (?LaunchOnChangeOwnerEvents@ball@@SAXH@Z) E:\projects\ProFCEngine\SoccerAI\anotherClass.obj   SoccerAI

it should work fine ,what i did wrong?

UPDATE

if i use template struct baseEvent::Event; LaunchOnChangeOwnerEvents will fix but if i do this in my main i get error again.

```
 #include "anotherClass.h"

 int main()
 {
         anotherClass c;
        ball::AddOnChangeOwnerEvent([](nullptr_t sender, int args)
        {
            std::cout << "here";
        });
         c.Update();

         return 0;
  }
```

Comment: is it the same error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Too long did not read**

The simplest solution is to add the following line at the end of `baseEvent.cpp`

```
template struct baseEvent::Event<nullptr_t, int>;
```

**Answer**

Let's assume that your main looks like this:

```
 #include "anotherClass.h"

 int main()
 {
         anotherClass c;

         c.Update();

         return 0;
  }
```

When we compile main.cpp

```
 g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp -o main.o
```

And check what symbols our translation unit needs/provides:

```
 $nm -gC main.o
 0000000000000000 T main
                  U anotherClass::Update()
```

`main.cpp` needs implementation of `anotherClass::Update`.

let's compile `anotherClass.cpp`

```
 g++ -std=c++11 -c anotherClass.cpp -o anotherClass.o
```

And again check what symbols our translation unit needs/provides:

```
$nm -gC anotherClass.o
[...]
0000000000000000 T anotherClass::Update()
                 U baseEvent::Event<decltype(nullptr), int>::LaunchEvents(decltype(nullptr), int)
[...]
```

`anotherClass.cpp` provides a lot of symbols I have removed them for clarity. As you can see during `anotherClass.cpp` compilation LaunchEvents for `nullptr_t, int` was not compiled, because compilator didn't have its definition.

When we check what `baseEvent.o` with `nm` we will learn it did not provide any symbols nor needs any.

```
nm -gC baseEvent.o
```

As I have written before the problem is that `anotherClass.cpp` have only declaration of `LaunchEvents` not is definition.

**Explicit instantiation**

The first way to go is to force instantiation of this template in `baseEvent.cpp`:

```
template struct baseEvent::Event<nullptr_t, int>;
```

If we check `baseEvent.o` after such change we will see that needed symbols will be provided in this translation unit:

```
$nm -gC baseEvent.o
[...]
0000000000000000 W baseEvent::Event<decltype(nullptr), int>::RemoveEvent(int)
0000000000000000 W baseEvent::Event<decltype(nullptr), int>::LaunchEvents(decltype(nullptr), int)
0000000000000000 W baseEvent::Event<decltype(nullptr), int>::LaunchEvents(baseEvent::Event<decltype(nullptr), int>, int)
0000000000000000 W baseEvent::Event<decltype(nullptr), int>::AddEvent(std::function<void (decltype(nullptr), int)>)
0000000000000000 W baseEvent::Event<decltype(nullptr), int>::AddEvent(std::function<void (baseEvent::Event<decltype(nullptr), int>, int)>)
[...]
```

**Moving template definition to header**

As @qxz stated in his/her answer you can move template implementation to the header. You can add inline function after class

```
#ifndef BASE_EVENT_H
#define BASE_EVENT_H

#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

class baseEvent
{
public:
[...]

    template<typename Sender, typename EventArgs>
    struct Event
    {
        int AddEvent(pureEvent<Sender, EventArgs>);
        void RemoveEvent(int);
        void LaunchEvents(Sender, EventArgs);
    private:
        eventMap<pureEvent<Sender,EventArgs>> Events;
    };
};

[...]

template <typename Sender, typename EventArgs>
inline void baseEvent::Event<Sender, EventArgs>::LaunchEvents(Sender sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Events.empty())return;
    for (auto& singleEvent : Events)
    {
        singleEvent.second(sender, e);
    }
}

#endif
```

Or add the implementation inside class definition

```
class baseEvent
{
public:
    [...]

    template<typename Sender, typename EventArgs>
    struct Event
    {
        [...]
        void LaunchEvents(Sender sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                if (Events.empty())return;

                for (auto& singleEvent : Events)
                {
                    singleEvent.second(sender, e);
                }
        }
    private:
        eventMap<pureEvent<Sender,EventArgs>> Events;
    };
};
```

If you do so the implementation will be provided in `anotherClass.o`:

```
$ nm -gC anotherClass.o  | grep LaunchEvent
0000000000000000 W baseEvent::Event<decltype(nullptr), int>::LaunchEvents(decltype(nullptr), int)
0000000000000000 W baseEvent::Event<decltype(nullptr), int>::LaunchEvents(baseEvent::Event<decltype(nullptr), int>, int)
```

Comment: i getting a new error updated the question can you help again?

Answer (score 1):

With template classes, you can't just put the implementation in a source file. The source file doesn't know what template parameters the function will be called with, so it doesn't generate any compiled functions. Hence you get a linker error that the function is 'unresolved."

You could fix this by moving the implementations into the header, inline with the class definition.

Comment: another way to go is explicit instantiation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by56e477.aspx

Comment: can you give me an example?